# Is DB a reserved word in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am building some tests with mocha and chai(expect).
Keeping it simple as I am learning about testing methodology as I go along.

I have a mysql db layer in a config file.
Testing the db parameters, I ran into a weird issue.

These db parameters test fine:

```
host= 'localhost',
user='foo',
password='bar',
```

The tests:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var db = require('../db/config.ini');

describe('Database Access', function() {
    it('HOST parameter should be a string', function() {
        expect(host).to.be.a('string');
    });
    it('USER parameter should be a string', function() {
        expect(user).to.be.a('string');
    });
    it('PASSWORD parameter should be a string', function() {
        expect(password).to.be.a('string');
    });
    it('DB parameter should be a string', function() {
        expect(db).to.be.a('string');
    });
    it('HOST parameter should equal localhost', function() {
        expect(host).to.equal('localhost');
    });
    it('USER parameter should equal foo', function() {
        expect(user).to.equal('foo');
    });
    it('PASSWORD parameter should equal bar', function() {
        expect(password).to.equal('bar');
    });
    it('DB parameter should equal thatone', function() {
        expect(context).to.equal('thatone');
    });
});
```

When I add the database to choose,

```
db='thatone';
```

The test fails the parameter because it reads it as an object.

```
  1) Database Access DB parameter should be a string:
     AssertionError: expected {} to be a string
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/db_tests.js:21:20)
```

If I change the variable name to "context" the test passes as expected.

I'm wondering if there is something obvious I am missing about using "db" as a variable.

**UPDATE**
Really stupid, novice level mistake.
So focused on learning testing methodology I didn't realize I had created the
'db' var as a require to the 'ini' and then referenced it later as though it was unique.

Really dumb. Rushing through this recklessly to get to a destination, and failing to follow some good methodology.

Comment: Is the result of `require('../db/config.ini')` a string? (Hint: not according to the error message.) You wouldn't want to call something *else* `db` because (a) last one wins, and (b) it'd be really, really confusing. As this question highlights.

Comment: Ok. Good point. Perhaps an 'ini' file is not the best method here.
I'm coming from a mostly Unix server background. Old tech ideas still manifesting.

Comment: An `ini` file or not isn't relevant (not the direction I'd take since you can just use an object), the issue is hiding an existing reference.

Comment: Well, yeah, I was not ignoring that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of executing this is not a string:

```
var db = require('../db/config.ini');
```

It seems you are trying to get a file in some INI dialect to be meaningfully interpreted by Node. **Node does not support this by default.** If you do not get an error while loading it, the most likely reason is that the text you have in there happens to also be valid JavaScript but since INI files do not contain proper code to export something (i.e. the file does not contain `exports.db = "something"` or `module.exports = { ... }` or something similar), then the module has the value `{}`.

You need to add one of the multiple npm packages that will automatically interpret an INI file and provide a meaningful value. I cannot recommend one as I don't use INI files in my software but you can [search npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search) for a package that will perform the translation for you.

Comment: Thanks. That was a meaningful and helpful explanation of what went wrong.

I didn't recognize I had created the 'db' already, and then was referencing it later as though it was new.